# filtering current date into a arraylist with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm building a filter AngularJS, to display only data that contains the current date in the query, at the moment I'm doing this, but I can not get it to work.

```
-J_Wjq2vkPJxCkmk3Wxp
  Estado: "pendiente"
  FechaActividad: "2014-11-11"
  NombreActividad: "Actividad 1"

  -J_WrCwULkPGRD5-mZ6z
  Estado: "aprobado"
  FechaActividad: "2014-10-11"
  NombreActividad: "Actividad 2"
```

This is the filter I try to build to build

```
 app.filter('fechas', function($filter)
{
 return function(input)
 {
  if(input == null){ return ""; }

  var _date = $filter('date')(new Date(input), 'MMM dd yyyy');

  return _date.toUpperCase();

 };
});
```

and so I am showing my html.

```
 <div ng-repeat="i in list | fechas">
<span>{{i.Estado}}</span>
<span>{{i.FechaActividad}}</span>
<span>{{i.NombreActividad}}</span>
</div>
```

also try to do the following but neither had resulted

```
 <div ng-repeat="i in list | fechas:['FechaActividad']">
```

**solution:**

Create a variable dt in $scope within controller as:

```
$scope.dt = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Change the HTML fragment as:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in data | filter: {FechaActividad: dt}">
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? Display records from today only ?

Comment: exactly, that's what I want to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the correct solution, the first parameter is the whole collection (input) 
inside the function just iterate the items and compare the values and return new array

```
   app.filter('fetchas', function($filter){
    return function(collection){
        var today = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'MMM dd yyyy');
        var newCollection = [];

        angular.forEach(collection, function(input){
            var formatted = $filter('date')(input, 'MMM dd yyyy');
            if(formatted == today){
                newCollection.push(input);
            }
        });
        console.log(newCollection);
        return newCollection;
    };
});
```

Comment: Care to explain your solution a little bit?